# Equation for next value on hysteresis curve

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have implemented a software module that outputs a hysteretical value with respect to a reference input value. The module does not model anything, it simply starts ramping the output up after the reference rises over $thld_{ON}$ and starts ramping the output down when the reference falls below $thld_{OFF}$. Outside of the ramping regions the output saturates high or low.

I can currently show the value at time $t$ during ramping for rising or falling separately, respectively:

$$
R_{t^r} = R_{t-1} + [(slope \times x)/ref], \\
R_{t^f} = R_{t-1} - [(slope \times x)/ref], \\
\forall R \in [0,1)
$$

I would like to create an equation that gives the value of the output at *any* time $t$, i.e. during rising falling or saturation such that $R_t$ is always equal to one single equation.

It is a long while since I have done any but the most simple of maths (my head is stuck thinking in terms of if statements!) and I'm having trouble knowing if and how I can do this

[image: hysteretic output]

Answer (score 0):

There are several equations in the article “An improved parametric model for hysteresis loop approximation” (R. V. Lapshin, Review of Scientific Instruments, vol. 91, iss. 6, no. 065106, 31 pp., 2020, DOI: 10.1063/5.0012931) that describe the piecewise-linear hysteresis loop Play shown on your picture.

[Piecewise-linear hysteresis loops: (a) Play with Gain, (b) Play with Gain without Whiskers (parallelogram loop), (c) Play with Attenuation, (d) Play with Attenuation without Whiskers, (e) Play (backlash), (f) Play without Whiskers, (g) Non-ideal Relay with Gain, (h) Non-ideal Relay with Gain without Whiskers, (i) Non-ideal Relay with Attenuation, (j) Non-ideal Relay with Attenuation without Whiskers, (k) Non-ideal Relay (Schmitt trigger), and (l) Non-ideal Relay without Whiskers (rectangular loop) built on triangular pulses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teZpB.png)

The article can be downloaded at https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0012931

Best regards,
Rostislav Lapshin